# Change Session ID Once Started

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I am using Zend framework 1 and I need to change the session id at runtime with a predefined prefix, however I am getting the following error "The session has already been started. The session id must be set first." The issue is that the session state still remains started even after calling the destroy and writeclose. I also tried using the php methods unset & destroy but still same issue.

```
$oldSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
Zend_Session::destroy();
Zend_Session::writeClose();

$sessId = "dskjfghdsjfhsdkf"; //Random hash
Zend_Session::setId("myprefix".$sessId);

$newSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
foreach($oldSession as $idx => $data){
    $newSession->$idx = $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not possible,

Snippet from Zend_Session.php:

```
 if (!self::$_unitTestEnabled && defined('SID')) {
        /** @see Zend_Session_Exception */
        require_once 'Zend/Session/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Session_Exception('The session has already been started.  The session id must be set first.');
    }
```

Comment: I know that's causing the issue however my question is how to get around it. IE: Force the session to be closed/destroyed.